# Docker volume - windows host and linux container

Tags: windows, docker, git-bash, docker-volume

I have this very simple Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:current-alpine3.14 AS baseImage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package* .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "watch"]
```

Then I run :
`docker build . -t myImage`

And then `docker run -p 8080:3000 -v /c/myFolder:/app myImage`

So basically I want a "shared" between the app folder in the container and the C:\myFolder on my host.

But it doesn't work :
For instance, if I update C:\myFolder\index.js, the changes doesnt occur in the container.

And here is what `docker inspect myContainer` returns under the Mounts section.
**Is it something to do with escaping / path format? Or am I missing something fundamental in working with volume ? or WORKDIR ?**

Mounts :
[image]
*The Mounts seems to consider **"Program Files/Git/app"** the destination / container folder but it should simply be **"/app"***

Binds:
[image]

Comment: In windows all is possible :(. Your docker run sentence seems fine. Al least the container starts and the app is working?  Just to try, enter to the container (docker exec...) and perform some change in the index.js and share us if is is detected by your app

Comment: Thx @JRichardsz. Yes the containers starts and work fine.
I am using an Alpine image therefore no bash is available...
The Mounts seems to consider  "Program Files/Git/app" the destination / container folder but  it should simply be "/app"

Comment: you're right @rzlvmp. It was a typo. I've edited it

Comment: in alpine you could use sh instead bash. Then inside, install nano with `apk add nano`. With that, edit the index.js and share us if the change is detected

Comment: A design goal of Docker is that an image contains an immutable copy of an application, and it's separate from any copy of the application that may or may not exist on the host.  Can you use Node without Docker for day-to-day development?

Comment: @DavidMaze  I think you're asking for some context.
The goal here is clearly to avoid the "it works on my machine" syndrome. The idea is to use our image for development (with a second stage build for prod) so people start working "locally" in the container (if that makes sense), then commit/push their changes into git (which includes the dockerfile). 

I hope it helps !

That being said, I still don't understand why the Mounts destination value == "/Program Files/Git/app" while it should only be "/app"
I think windows is kind of overriding the volume path...

Comment: @JRichardsz trying to run exec triggers a weird error :

```$ docker exec myContainer /bin/sh


OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown```
why is it looking for C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh ??

Comment: @JRichardsz ```docker exec -it myContainer sh``` worked.
And updating index.js directly in the container worked fine as well. Nodemon correctly logged the changes too

Comment: @JRichardsz but local update of index.js still not taken into account in the container

Comment: try this: `docker run -it -v /c/myFolder:/app ubuntu` and verify if this simple container is able to handle the volume. Create a file on /c/myFolder and then in the container, check if the new file exist  in the  /app folder

Comment: I've just fixed it. The issue comes from running the command in Git Bash
The excat same command ran in CMD worked as expected.
Looks like Git Bash was converting the /app destination path into /programFiles/Git/app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the command

`docker run -p 8080:3000 -v /c/myFolder:/app myImage`
was run **with gitbash for windows**

Running the exact same command with **CMD solved my issue**.

it looks like GitBash was converting the `/app` destination folder into `\Program Files\Git\app`